How to implement multi-x axis in a ListContourPlot?
I have a data file called data.csv which is of the form {{x1,y1, z1}, ...,  {xn, yn, zn}}}, where $0\le x \le 180$ and $0\le y \le 360$. I am plotting data using ListContourPlot. Presently the $x$-axis tick labels are shown both top and bottom. (See below)

I want to replace the top $x$-axis with a different variable called $w(x)$, which gives the value  for $w$ as a function of $x$. But I do not know how to do this. The function $0\le w(x) \le 90$.
I can build a table for $w(x)$, such that
(*Define v1[x] using degree to radian conversion for x*)
v1[x_] := 1/(2 - Cos[x Degree])*{0, Sin[x Degree], Cos[x Degree]};

(*Define v2[x]*)
v2[x_] := ({0, 0, 1} - v1[x]);

(*Define w[x] with special handling for x=0*)
w[x_] := Simplify[If[x == 0, 90, VectorAngle[{0, 0, 1}, v2[x]]*180/Pi]];

(*Generate a list of values for w[x] from 0 to 180,incrementing by 1 degree*)
valuesForW = Table[N[w[x]], {x, 0, 180, 1}]; 

But this is as far as I got. I do not know how to implement this into ListContourPlot so that $w(x)$ appears on the top $x$-axis and the corresponding $x$ values appear along the bottom $x$-axis.
To make things a bit more complicated the $w(x)$ runs from left to right in descending order while the $x$ values run from left to right in ascending order.
Below is the complete code. Any suggestions would be most welcome.
data = Import["path_to_file\\data.csv"];


(*Define v1[x] using degree to radian conversion for x*)
v1[x_] := 1/(2 - Cos[x Degree])*{0, Sin[x Degree], Cos[x Degree]};

(*Define v2[x]*)
v2[x_] := ({0, 0, 1} - v1[x]);

(*Define w[x] with special handling for x=0*)
w[x_] := Simplify[If[x == 0, 90, VectorAngle[{0, 0, 1}, v2[x]]*180/Pi]];

(*Generate a list of values for w[x] from 0 to 180,incrementing by 1 degree*)
valuesForW = Table[N[w[x]], {x, 0, 180, 1}]; (*I do not know how to implement this as the top x-axis*)

(*Major and minor ticks lengths*)
factor = scale*3.4;
majorLength = factor*0.015;
minorLength = factor*0.0075;

(*Define custom major and minor ticks for the vertical and horizontal \
axes*)
xMajorTicks = 
  Table[{i, Style[ToString[i], FontSize -> frameFontSize], {majorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}];
xMinorTicks = Table[{i, "", {minorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 180, 5}];

yMajorTicks = Table[{i, Style[ToString[i], FontSize -> frameFontSize], {majorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 360, 45}];
yMinorTicks = Table[{i, "", {minorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 360, 9}];

(*Combine major and minor ticks*)
xComboTicks = Join[xMajorTicks, xMinorTicks];
yComboTicks = Join[yMajorTicks, yMinorTicks];

(*Plot the data*)
ListContourPlot[
 data,
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[If[# <= 0.1, 0, 1.0], ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}][#]] &),
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSlant -> Plain, FontFamily -> font, legendFontSize, Black},
 FrameTicks -> {xComboTicks, yComboTicks},
 ImageSize -> 400,
 InterpolationOrder -> 1,
 ContourStyle -> {Magenta, Dashed},
 Contours -> 10,
 Background -> White,
 PlotRangePadding -> 0
 ]


With FrameTicks->{{left,right},{bottom,top}}, you can specify the ticks for each edge

Hi MelaGo, Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, the problem with your suggestion is that W(x) does not correspond to the value of x. For example, when x = 90 w(90) = 26.5. But if you drew a vertical line from x= 90 (from the bottom x-axis) all the way to the top x-axis  you would find it lands on w=90, instead of w = 26.5. Perhaps I need to apply some scaling by 2. But I don't know how to do that.

@QuantumKid, please look at the documentation for FrameTicks, 4th bullet point. You will find that the "location" of the tick does not need to match its label. Namely, you can put tick with label 26.5 at position 90.

Hi Domen. Thanks for your input. It is much appreciated. I have managed to solve the problem another way. (See below, if interested)

I have managed to create a top x-axis which represents w(x). The plot now looks like this:

The modified code is given by:
(* Major and minor ticks lengths *)
scale = 1;
factor = scale*3.4;
majorLength = factor*0.015;
minorLength = factor*0.0075;


(*Define v1[x] using degree to radian conversion for x*)
v1[x_] := 1/(2 - Cos[x Degree])*{0, Sin[x Degree], Cos[x Degree]};

(*Define v2[x]*)
v2[x_] := ({0, 0, 1} - v1[x]);

(*Define w[x] with special handling for x=0*)
w[x_] := Simplify[
   If[x == 0, 90, VectorAngle[{0, 0, 1}, v2[x]]*180/Pi]];

(*Generate a list of values for w[x] from 0 to 180,incrementing by 30 \
degrees*)
MajorWTicks = 
  Table[{x, 
    Style[Round[N[w[x]]], FontSize -> frameFontSize], {majorLength, 
     0}}, {x, 0, 180, 30}];
MinorWTicks = Table[{x, "", {minorLength, 0}}, {x, 0, 180, 5}];

(*Combine major and minor ticks for w(x)*)
ComboWTicks = Join[MajorWTicks, MinorWTicks];

(* Major and minor ticks lengths *)
factor = scale*3.4;
majorLength = factor*0.015;
minorLength = factor*0.0075;

(*Define custom major and minor ticks for the vertical and horizontal \
axes*)
xMajorTicks = 
  Table[{i, 
    Style[ToString[i], FontSize -> frameFontSize], {majorLength, 
     0}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}];
xMinorTicks = Table[{i, "", {minorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 180, 5}];

yMajorTicks = 
  Table[{i, 
    Style[ToString[i], FontSize -> frameFontSize], {majorLength, 
     0}}, {i, 0, 360, 45}];
yMinorTicks = Table[{i, "", {minorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 360, 9}];

(*Combine major and minor ticks*)
xComboTicks = Join[xMajorTicks, xMinorTicks];
yComboTicks = Join[yMajorTicks, yMinorTicks];

(*Extract x-values for gridlines*)
xGridLines = xMajorTicks[[All, 1]];

(*Import data*)
data = Import[
   "path_to_file\\data.csv"];

(*Plot the data with w[x] on the top x-axis*)
ListContourPlot[
 data,
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[If[# <= 0.1, 0, 1.0], 
     ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}][#]] &),
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", "w(x)"},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSlant -> Plain, FontFamily -> font, 
   legendFontSize, Black}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yComboTicks, yComboTicks}, {xComboTicks, 
    ComboWTicks}},
 ImageSize -> 400,
 InterpolationOrder -> 1,
 ContourStyle -> {Magenta, Dashed},
 Contours -> 10,
 Background -> White,
 GridLines -> {xGridLines, None},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]

